# Cannot read output of open in Perl

Tags: perl

I have this little bit of code in a while statement `while(<PS>)` and it will not execute and read the output of the `open(PS,"blabla")` code.

How do I resolve this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#

my $IPendnum = 1;
my $IPrange = 0;
my $START = 1;

while ($START == 1) {
        print "Pinging IP : 192.168." . $IPrange . "." . $IPendnum . "\n";
        open (PS, "fping 192.168." . $IPrange . "." . $IPendnum);
        while(<PS>) {
                chop ($_);
                if (/is alive/) {
                        print "The following IP : 192.168." . $IPrange . "." . $IPendnum . " is online! \n";
                } else {
                        print "The following IP : 192.168." . $IPrange . "." . $IPendnum . " is currently offline! \n";
                }
        }

        if ($IPendnum >= 255) {
                $IPrange += 1;
                $IPendnum = 1;
        } else {
                $IPendnum += 1;
        }
        print "Moving to the next IP address \n";
        sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Would this be better suited for Stack Overflow?

Comment: I've tried Stack Overflow they recomended I came here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open a file.  You run a command like this:

```
open (PS, "-|", "fping 192.168.$IPrange.$IPendnum");
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU SIR ARE THE MAN THANKS THANKS THANS MUCH LOVE